# Bound variance of sum of indicators

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph such that $|V| = n$, $|E| = \Theta(n^{3/2})$ and the maximal degree is $O(n^{1/2})$. Define $V'$ to be a set of vertices, chosen by adding each vertex to $V'$ with probability $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. The goal is to prove that with probability at least $(1- \alpha)$ (for all positive $\alpha$), the graph induced by $V'$ has at least $(1-\alpha)\sqrt{n}$ edges for all $n$ large enough.

I tried to do the following:

Define for each edge an indicator $I_e$ which equals to 1 iff the edges $e$ is in $G'$, and $I = \sum_e I_e$. Clearly, $P(I_e = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $E(I) = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$. Now, we can use Chebyshev inequality: $P(|I - \sqrt{n} | > \alpha \sqrt(n))< \frac{Var(I)}{\alpha^2 n}$. So, in order to complete the proof, I need to bound the variance. The thing is that "simple" bound doesn't work (the fraction doesn't go to 0 as $n$ grows). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the condition that maximal degree is $O(n^{1/2})$. This means the total number of paths of length $2$ is $O(n^{2})$. This shows that $\mathrm{Var}(I) = O(\sqrt{n}).$

This is because
$$
\mathrm{Var}(I) = \sum_{\{u,v\} \in E,\{s,t\} \in E} \mathbb{E}(I_{u,v} I_{s,t})-\mathbb{E}(I_{u,v})\mathbb{E}(I_{s,t}).
$$
There are three cases --- (a) the two edges $\{u,v\}$ and $\{s,t\}$ are either disjoint, (b) or share one node, i.e., they form a path of length $2$, (c) or are the same. The disjoint pairs contribute $0$ to the sum. The $2$-path pairs contribute $O(\sqrt{n})$. And the identical pairs contribute $O(\mathbb{E}(I))$. So we are done!

Comment: How can you bound the number of 2 paths using the maximal degree?

Comment: @Joel You really should try to fill some gaps by yourself. Good for your health!